# How can I implement Apple's "Snooze" functionality in their Clock app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, clock, localnotification

I'm diving into iOS development and am building my own alarm clock app to become familiar with the platform and SDK.  One of the API's I'm currently learning is the Local Notifications API, which I assume is the same API Apple uses to implement their alarms in their Clock app.

What I don't understand is how they implement their "Snooze" functionality.  As I understand it, Local Notifications allow you to present to the user an alert box that has at most two buttons when your app isn't running in the foreground, one button for dismissing the alert and one button for taking the user to your app.  In Apple's Clock app, however, it appears the user is presented with an alert box with two buttons, one button to dismiss the alarm and one button to "Snooze" and reschedule the alarm without launching the Clock app.  My questions are...

1. When the user clicks the "Snooze" button, how do you think Apple is rescheduling the Local Notification for the alarm without launching the Clock app?  Do you think they're using their own private APIs that circumvent the limitations of the Local Notifications that only allow for two options?  Or do you think they're launching the Clock app to reschedule the Local Notification, they just don't show the app launching and quitting?
2. The documentation says the "alertAction" property of the Local Notification is the text to be displayed on the right button of the alert box and the slider bar of the lock screen.  In Apple's Clock app, however, the "Snooze" text is the left button in the alert box, nor is it the Slider bar text.  Why is this backwards?

Thanks so much in advance for your thoughts!

Comment: Why would u assume apple is using local notifications? They actually are using some undocumented for reschedule the snooze, since right now we cant schedule a local notification without the app reopening

Comment: Well I guess I assumed that because that's what the functionality most closely resembled.

Comment: @Daniel - unless you work for Apple, you're the one making assumptions :)

Comment: Sure, but still, you cant schedule local notifications once the app has already shut down (and even when local notifications are delivered), so apple is still using some undocumented API, the only (documented) way to do this i think would be to have the "snooze" button reopen the app and reschedule a notification, then close the app... donno maybe im wrong :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The local notification API does not have any mechanism to do what you want. The alarm clock app is almost certainly not using any of the infrastructure for local notifications, it predates them. Even if it is factored onto some of the infrastructure provided by local notifications, it is certainly not using the public APIs.

You should [file](http://bugreporter.apple.com/) a bug requesting that this functionality be added.

Comment: I've filed this as bug #9381428. Good idea!

Comment: I've filed it again as bug #11115712, almost a year later :-\